# php Merge multidemisional array based on 2 subkeys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have 2 array's and would like to merge them together and is the item is not found in the second array insert a key with empty value. 
Basicly add items from array2 in array1 matching 2 array1 subkeys;
Array2 does not have to be the same length as array 1, its alsways smaller in length.

array1

```
[0][item] = 'aaaa'
   [type] = '1234'

[1][item] = 'aaaa'
   [type] = '6789'

[2][item] = 'bbbb'
   [type] = '1234'

[3][item] = 'bbbb'
   [type] = '6789'
```

And array2:

```
[0][item] = 'aaaa'
   [type] = '1234'
   [feature] = 'www'

[1][item] = 'aaaa'
   [type] = '6789'
   [feature] = 'www'
```

result:

```
[0][item] = 'aaaa'
   [type] = '1234'
   [feature] = 'www'

[1][item] = 'aaaa'
   [type] = '6789'
   [feature] = 'www'

[2][item] = 'bbbb'
   [type] = '1234'
   [feature] = ''

[3][item] = 'bbbb'
   [type] = '6789'
   [feature] = ''
```

I tried several suggestions foudn here, they all come down to one dimesnional arrays or matching the index. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let PHP do the matching for you, via array keys:

```
$result=array();
foreach ($array1 as $item) {
  $item['feature']='';
  $result[$item['item'].'-'.$item['type']]=$item;
}
foreach ($array2 as $item) {
  $result[$item['item'].'-'.$item['type']]['feature']=$item['feature'];
}
$result=array_values($result);
```

Comment: I tried it, works like great !

nice trick to link the 2 keys together, was thinking of someting simular but the in te array itself using a extra unique key (combine the 2 searchkey's) .
This is much easier, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
foreach ($array1 as $key=>$value){
   if (isset($array2[$key]['feature'])){
      $array1[$key]['feature'] = $array2[$key]['feature'];
   } else {
      $array1[$key]['feature'] = '';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some thing like this:

```
array_walk($array, function ($arr, $key) use ($array2) {
   if (array_key_exists($key, $array2) && is_array($array2[$key])) {
      $arr = array_merge($arr, $array2[$key]);
   }
});
print_r($array); // Will have all missed keys from $array2
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the empty string for 'feature', in a future iteration you can check it with isset. Keep things simple and don't create structures that you dont need or are difficult to maintain. This will work for n number of subkeys and needs no maintenance.

```
$ar1 = array(
        array('item' => 'aaaa', 'type' => '1234'),
        array('item' => 'aaaa', 'type' => '6789'),
        array('item' => 'bbbb', 'type' => '1234'),
        array('item' => 'bbbb', 'type' => '6789')
    );
    $ar2 = array(
        array('item' => 'aaaa', 'type' => '1234','feature' => 'www'),
        array('item' => 'aaaa', 'type' => '6789','feature' => 'www')
    );
    for ($i = 0;$i<count($ar1);$i++) {
        if (array_key_exists($i, $ar2)){
            $result[] = array_merge($ar2[$i], $ar1[$i]);
        } else {
            $result[] = $ar1[$i];
        }
    }

// result
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [item] => aaaa
        [type] => 1234
        [feature] => www
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [item] => aaaa
        [type] => 6789
        [feature] => www
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [item] => bbbb
        [type] => 1234
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [item] => bbbb
        [type] => 6789
    )

)
```

Comment: this does not work, it will append all itmes from array2 into array1 startating with an index counting up starting from the highest in array1